# What is this Android icon that looks like a gauge with a leaf?

Tags: android, icons, samsung

Screenshot of the icon below, with a square drawn around it.

Note: This icon is not permanently displayed. The notification shade must be pulled down for the icon to appear in the notification bar.[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) is for users and power users of Android. See: [How can I deduce/identify an app from a notification icon?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37443/3573)

Answer (score 1):

The icon is showing the status of the Samsung "Performance Profile".